# Enumerable.Sum() of double to return null if list contains null

Tags: c#, linq

```
var num = new List<double?>{null};  
var result = num.Sum(d => (double?)d);
Console.WriteLine(result is null);
```

How to make this return true?

Comment: You can't make `Sum` do something that it doesn't do. You would need to check first whether there are any non-null items and then only call `Sum` if there are.

Comment: What if it contains `null` and `0`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, the OP should be explicit but I interpreted that to be "if list contains ONLY null", i.e. no items with a value.

Comment: I would fallback to `double.NaN` - https://dotnetfiddle.net/MtDkxK

Answer (score 0):

I'm don't think it is possible in "one go", but you can do something like this to get the desired result:

```
double? sum = d.Any((x) => x == null) ? null : d.Sum();
```

Comment: The question is well-written but I interpreted as meaning if the list ONLY contains `null` then the sum should be `null`. In that case, you'd have to invert your check to look for any items that weren't `null` and switch the outputs.